# Rails: Storing a 256 bit checksum as binary in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, binary, checksum, bignum

I'm trying to store a SHA-2 256 bit checksum in a column:

```
create_table :checksums do |t|
  t.binary :value, :null => false, :limit => 32
end
```

I'm storing in the value like so:

```
c = Checksum.new
big_num = Digest::SHA2.new.update("some string to be checksum'd").hexdigest.to_i(16)
c.value = big_num
```

On the assignment of big_num to c.value I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for #<Bignum:0x00000001ea48f8>
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be storing your SHA2 in a binary column then you probably just want to use the [`digest` method](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/Class.html#method-c-digest) to get the raw SHA2 bytes:

```
big_num = Digest::SHA2.new.update("some string to be checksum'd").digest
```

Your SHA2 is a 256 bit value (32 bytes) and that won't fit in a Fixnum (which uses less than 32 or 64 bits due to internal bookkeeping bits), that's why you end up with a Bignum when you call `.hexdigest.to_i(16)`. Binary columns are really just sequences of bytes (i.e. binary *strings*) and part of the encoding mechanism is probably using [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) to get the bytes into the format that the database expects. You're assigning a Bignum to something that expects to see a String and that doesn't work that well.

You could also use a simple string column (with `:limit=> 64`) to store the `.hexdigest` value instead of a 32 byte binary column.

Comment: @Ben: You're welcome. The connection between the error message and the real problem was pretty obscure in this case.